# Difference between "With all due respect" and "Without disrespect"

Tags: differences, phrase-meaning, context

What is the difference between the below two phrases?

> With all due respect

and

> Without disrespect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**with all due respect**, as defined by [Cambridge Dictionaries](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/with-all-due-respect):

> **used to express polite disagreement in a formal situation:**
>
> *With all due respect, Sir, I cannot agree with your last statement.*

There's actually no official definition that I could find for **without disrespect**, so I'll turn my attention to its equivalent **no disrespect**, which [Cambridge Dictionaries](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/disrespect?q=no%2Bdisrespect%2Bto%2Bsb) defines as:

> **used before you criticize someone in order not to sound rude:**
>
> *No disrespect to Julie, but this department worked perfectly well
> before she started here.*

As can be seen above, **with all due respect** is often used to politely address a person you're disagreeing with, while **no disrespect** is utilized for the purpose of not coming off rude when criticizing another person.

Aside from the obvious difference in meaning, **with all due respect** is very formal and a quintessentially posh phrase. **no disrespect**, on the other hand, is less formal and more widely used than its counterpart.

Comment: Please note that both words can also be used sarcastically. Despite suggesting courtesy and mutual respect, the two can also be utilized to preface uncourtly and, sometimes, blatantly offensive statements. An example is Paul Gogarty's speech in front of the parliament, in which he stated: [With all due respect, in the most unparliamentarily language, fuck you Deputy Stagg! Fuck you](https://youtu.be/ugailEn8U5o).

Comment: In US English, "with all due respect" is a cliche heard in most any register, though "no disrespect" sounds less formal and is used to talk about third parties more than directly to someone you're about to criticize.